# Question about the basis of the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

If a topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $S$ has to contain $S$ and $\varnothing$, does $\varnothing$ need to be an element of the basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathcal{T}$ or is it simply considered an appended object?  I will write the formal statement I'm looking at so hopefully you can help me with exactly what I have in mind.

Let $C_\mathbb{Q}$ be the set of all Cauchy equivalence classes of rational numbers.  Denote the elements of $C_\mathbb{Q}$ with the notation $[x]$.  Define the real numbers such that

$$ x\in\mathbb{R}\quad\iff\quad x=[x]\subset C_\mathbb{Q}  ~~.$$

Toward my question, consider the basis of the usual topology $\mathcal{T}$ as

$$   \mathcal{B}=\big\{  (a,b)  ~\big|~  [a],[b] \subset C_\mathbb{Q} ,~ a< b\big\}~~.  $$

Most specifically, my question regards the $a<b$ condition on the sets in the basis.  This condition requires that the $\varnothing\not\in\mathcal{B}$.  Would it be better, then, to write

$$   \mathcal{B}=\big\{  (a,b)  ~\big|~  [a],[b] \subset C_\mathbb{Q} ,~ a\leq b\big\}~~,  $$

where the interval $(a,a)$ is identically $(a,a)=\varnothing$ because $a$ itself is not included in the interval and neither is any other number?  THANKS!!!

Comment: I don't want to post a definitive answer, but my take would be that one does not need the empty set to be in the topology base. Any open set is expressible as a union of base sets, and the empty set is always expressible as the empty union.

Comment: Yes.  I neglected to consider the empty union!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to include $\varnothing$ in the base, but it is not an appended object. If $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for a topology $\mathscr{T}$, by definition $\mathscr{T}=\{\bigcup\mathscr{S}:\mathscr{S}\subseteq\mathscr{B}\}$. Take $\mathscr{S}=\varnothing$, the empty collection of basic open sets: then $\bigcup\mathscr{S}=\varnothing$, so you automatically get $\varnothing\in\mathscr{T}$.